# Proving operator equality with exponentials

Tags: lie-groups, matrix-exponential

I'm currently trying to prove that for two Operators $A,B$ with the property $[A,[A,B]]=[B,[A,B]]=0$ ($[\cdot,\cdot]$ being the commutator) the following is true
$$e^{A+B}=e^Ae^Be^{-\frac{1}{2}[A,B]}.$$
The Hint was to consider $f(\lambda) = e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}e^{-\lambda(A+B)}$ and show that $f'(\lambda)=\lambda [A,B]f(\lambda)$. The problem is that when I calculate $f'(\lambda)$ I get the following
$$\begin{align}f'(\lambda) &= \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}e^{\lambda A}\right)e^{\lambda B}e^{-\lambda(A+B)} +e^{\lambda A}\left(\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}e^{\lambda B}\right]e^{-\lambda (A+B)}+e^{\lambda B}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda}e^{-\lambda (A+B)}\right]\right)\\ 
&= Ae^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}e^{-\lambda(A+B)} +e^{\lambda A}Be^{\lambda B}e^{-\lambda(A+B)}-e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}(A+B)e^{-\lambda(A+B)},\end{align}$$
which certainly isn't what I should get (especially the missing $\lambda$ is giving me some headache, not sure where that should come from).

But even if I assume $f'(\lambda)=\lambda [A,B]f(\lambda)$ to be true I struggle to come to the desired result. This is obviously a differential equation in $f$ with the solution $f(\lambda)=C\exp(-\lambda^2/2~[A,B])$, where $C$ is some constant. If we now set $C=1$ and $\lambda =-1$ and equal this to the given $f(\lambda)$ we get
$$e^{\frac{1}{2}[A,B]}=e^{-A}e^{-B}e^{A+B} \Leftrightarrow e^{A+B}= e^Be^Ae^{\frac{1}{2}[A,B]}.$$
So the sign of one of the exponentials is wrong as well as the order of the exponentials.

---

**Questions**:

1. What am I doing wrong when calculating the derivative?
2. Is it not the right approach to try to solve the differential equation or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: I [googled](https://www.google.ca/search?q=e%5E(A%2BB)%3De%5EA+e%5EB+e%5E(%E2%88%92%5BA%2CB%5D%2F2)&oq=e%5E(A%2BB)%3De%5EA+e%5EB+e%5E(%E2%88%92%5BA%2CB%5D%2F2)&aqs=chrome..69i57&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and found [this (appendix)](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/751.mf1i.fall02/CoherentStates.pdf) and [this](http://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~mehen/760/ProblemSets/BCH.pdf).

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is sound, but you must pursue it to its logical implications.

You note that by the basic [Hadamard lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), given the centrality of the commutator (it commutes with everything),
$$
\bbox[yellow]{e^{\lambda B} A e^{-\lambda B}= A + \lambda [B,A]},
$$
while the remaining terms vanish! So the adjoint action on *A* is almost trivial.

By the same token,
$$
e^{\lambda A} (e^{\lambda B} A e^{-\lambda B})e^{-\lambda A}  = A + \lambda [B,A] .
$$

So you simply pursue your calculation,
$$ f'(\lambda) = 
 A(e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}e^{-\lambda(A+B)}) +e^{\lambda A}B    e^{-\lambda A}(e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}e^{-\lambda(A+B)})-e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}(A+B)e^{-\lambda B}e^{-\lambda A}(e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B}e^{-\lambda(A+B)})\\
=    (A -(A+\lambda [B,A]) ) f (\lambda)= \lambda [A,B] f (\lambda) . $$

The solution to this differential equation is
$$
f(\lambda) = e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2} [A,B]}  f(0)= e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2} [A,B]}.
$$

The degenerate limit of the Zassenhaus formula (see WP section) then follows,
$$
e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2} [A,B]}=  e^{  \lambda A}e^{ \lambda B} e^{ -\lambda (A+B)} ,
$$
which you should be able to check is completely equivalent to your desideratum formula through inversion, $ e^{- \lambda B}e^{ - \lambda A}e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2} [A,B]}=e^{ -\lambda (A+B)} $, restriction, $\lambda =-1$, and *redefinition*, $A\leftrightarrow B$.